# Visual studio 2010 Errors out on starting "-832" is not a valid value for property "width"

Tags: visual-studio-2010

My Visual Studio 2010 was working fine this morning (I run in in XP sP3 under Paralles) I restarted the entire laptop and I started getting this error. I even uninstalled VS2010, deleted the Visual Studio 20010 directory on the My Documents area and reinstalled it, and it is still giving me that error every time I try to start it.
I'm not sure if stackoverflow is the place to ask it, but I am at my wits end trying to get this running again (trying to avoid rebuilding the entire Virtual PC) Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Not sure how this is caused, but possibly related to having multiple monitors - I have been alternating between running 1 or 2 monitors.  Found a solution here:

http://rainabba.blogspot.com/2010/07/visual-studio-2010-wont-start-120-is.html

Basically, the erroneous negative width value(s) are stored in the registry, not on disk, so try this solution before the other destructive solutions in this SO question.

Fire up regedit, and navigate to:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\MainWindow
```

Edit the registry value, replacing any negative numbers with positive numbers (I replaced two instances of '-1' with '200')

Comment: VS2012 still has this bug.  Amazing.  I get it after switching to/from a projector a few times (using parallels too).

Comment: I switch screens all the time and connect often to my VS machine via RDP. Never had a problem until now. For VS2003 the path is HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\MainWindow

Comment: VS2015 still has this bug!! Switching from 4k monitor back to laptop.

Comment: For those who don't use regedit very often, `MainWindow` is a value inside of the directory `10.0` (or 14.0 for VS2015).  You have to click on the `10.0` folder to see the values that it contains, not just look in the tree on the left.

Comment: FYI VS 2015: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\MainWindow

Comment: Same issue with SSMS 2016... 
I deleted the MainWindow value at
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\13.0
Started SSMS, it was full screen and upon closing it the value was recreated...

Comment: Let's vote! https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/17963866-please-fix-8-year-annoying-bug-is-not-a-valid-va

Comment: I had an instance of this in MS SSMS as well when switching laptop from multiple to single monitors. I suspect this is a bug in windows more than in visual studio

Answer (score 8):

Starting with Visual Studio 2017, settings are now stored in a private registry hive. You will need to first load the VS2017 registry hive:

1. Select HKEY_USER in regedit.exe
2. File -> Load Hive
3. Browse to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_{INSTANCE}`
4. Select `privateregistry.bin` and click open
5. Give the loaded hive a name such as `VS2017`
6. Once the hive is loaded, locate the MainWindow value and fix the negative value in it.
7. The private hive can only be used by one application, so you will now need to select the hive you just loaded and unload it with `File -> Unload`

As for locating which instance is the default instance, I just looked for the most recently update file.

Comment: My hero! A slightly more short-hand (and universal) path for step 3 is `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio`\15.0_{INSTANCE}

Comment: VS2017RC: You can also rename MainWindow to something else like MainWindow_Old if you are unsure of which value to change allowing VisualStudio to reset this value.

Comment: Thanks @AdamPlocher, I updated the answer with your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, I got stuck with this and was not able to use VS2017 anymore.

Answer (score 4):

This solution of changing any negative values to a positive value in the MainWindow registry entry also works for Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - tested on v13.0.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\13.0\ MainWindow
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran in the same trouble with Visual Studio 2013.
I've tried the methods described in the other answers, but the one that worked was modifying in the registers.  It seems the Registers have changed since VS 2010. 
For VS 2013, you have to modify

> HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-1181729300-1976498228-1094237608-1001\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\MainWindow

Just make sure there's no negative value. I replaced `-580` with `100`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

regedit fixed the problem...searched for the invalid width number under the microsoft key...(found key=MainWindow). Edited the value and removed the 'negative' character.

Answer (score -1):

Do you see anything in the application event log?

Try these

```
devenv /ResetSettings 
devenv /installvstemplates
```

Delete contents in here:

```
%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplatesCache
```

Comment: This should really be a comment, and no none of those work.

Answer (score -1):

Try deleting files under `<username>\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Settings`.  That's where your user preferences are stored, including (I think) which windows you placed where.  These are not deleted when you uninstall or reinstall VS, so if something is botched in there it will still be botched after a reinstall.  Also look for droppings under `<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0`.