# Is this solvable ‘-4’ is not a valid value for property ‘Width’ ..?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visual studio 2010 Errors out on starting “-832” is not a valid value for property “width”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838169/visual-studio-2010-errors-out-on-starting-832-is-not-a-valid-value-for-proper)

This error is getting when ever i used to open microsoft visual studio 2010. I am unable to open the IDE.

Comment: Is this just opening VS with no solution whatsoever or opening your solution?

Answer (score 9):

[This](http://rainabba.blogspot.com/2010/07/visual-studio-2010-wont-start-120-is.html) blog describes how to fix the problem

You have to edit "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\MainWindow" in the registry so it doesn't have negative values in it