# Visual Studio 2010 won't create new project

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I could open Visual Studio 2010 no problem, but I got error window when I try to create any new project

[image]

After I searched the Internet I found some similar questions, for example [Visual studio 2010 Errors out on starting "-832" is not a valid value for property "width"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838169/visual-studio-2010-errors-out-on-starting-832-is-not-a-valid-value-for-proper) and it links to a blog http://rainabba.blogspot.com/2010/07/visual-studio-2010-wont-start-120-is.html which suggests to modify the registry to change any negative values. But my values are all positive

[image]

I really don't know what to do now.

Comment: Did you try some of the other suggestions on that question?  Particularly the `devenv /ResetSettings` answer?

Comment: @JPeroutek I just give it a try, and it does not help.